# Issues creating a Multi list for mobile dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am playing around with this tutorial to create a mobile dropdown menu.

https://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly

Everything works fine but once I add a new  with extra lists inside a previous  tag. The dropdown menu tends to not work as it should. I tried changing the css but had no luck.

Its displaying all the list without user having to click on it. If i add a new multi list to the previous  tag.

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
<a href="#nav">Show navigation</a>
<a href="#">Hide navigation</a>
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li class="active"><a href="?home">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="?blog" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Blog</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="?blog" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Test</span></a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="?design">One</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="?work" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Work</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?webdesign">Web Design</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="?about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I will not post the entire code here as there is too many css elements. please have a look at the code below.

Running example.

https://jsfiddle.net/cys670Lh/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use when hover `>` to snipe the current child and not all descendents, then add a new `hover` rule for the next submenu...

```
 #nav > ul > li:hover > ul
    {
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
#nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover ul
    {
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6u2d48p1/)**

Anyway, as a humble suggestion, I would not use hover to show the menu subcategories... specially if you aim at mobile device. I would use event on click insteed with javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much :) really appreciate the help

Comment: Np. would luck with your project

Comment: Thank you I need it haha